# New Rails project without rails cmd

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I like to keep my global gemset as small as possible (only bundler and no rails) and install project-specifc gems individually for each rails project. Consequently, **I do not have the rails command line tool in my global gemset**, which makes it hard for me to create a new rails project from scratch. Is there a way to setup a new rails project without the command line tool? This way I can keep my global gemset as lean as possible. Any Ideas?

Cheers,

Gerardo

FYI: Normally, I include this file `.bundle/config` to my rails projects to install the gems locally:

```
---
BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
```

Comment: Talk about self-inflicted pain :)

Comment: "- Doctor, it hurts when I do this. - Then don't do this."

Comment: But seriously, how do you imagine it would work, doing the job of the tool without the tool?

Comment: If you want a rails project, why do you not want the rails gems?  Aren't they going to be essential?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about keeping your global gemset lean in this way. Leverage tools like rbenv, bundler, binstubs and your gemfiles. Trust them and don't worry too much about what's installed.

Answer (score 3):

Create app folder - say `test_app`.

Now put Gemfile there with

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "rails"
```

Install gem: `cd test_app && bundle install --path vendor/bundle`
Now you have rails within this folder.
`bundle exec rails new ../test_app --force` will init new app, rewrite Gemfile and puts everything you need. Btw all gem now will be installed in `vendor/bundle`.

Comment: Worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

Make sure you have `bundler` gem installed.

Create a directory named rails and create a Gemfile with the following contents

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
```

Now run `bundle install --path .bundle`

This will provide you rails executable and you can now create new rails projects using:

```
bundle exec rails new path/to/my_app
```